# jquery selectMenu refresh doesn't work

Tags: jquery, select-menu

I have a selectMenu that I initialized and later I want to populate it with some data:

```
$.each(data, function (Key, Value) {
    $('#ddlReportFarms').append($("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", Value.ID)
    .text(Value.Name));
});                    
$('#ddlReportFarms').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

this doesn't work for some reason, the new items are not display.
if I do this instead of the refresh:

```
$('#ddlReportFarms').selectmenu();
```

the items are displayed, but when this happens again, 
the selectMenu duplicates itself (appears twice) and becomes buggy..

anyone?
thanks
Igal

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to do it like this:

```
[... your other code...]
$('#ddlReportFarms').selectmenu({'refresh': true});
```

Comment: In no version of jQuery UI selectmenu there is a parameter for the refresh method, so this answer is wrong. I have no idea who marks this as correct...

Comment: I believe the API has changed

Comment: As I'm the maintainer of both jQuery UI Selectmenu forks I'm pretty sure thats not the case. Your proposed code is not even valid UI API code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks MilkyWayJoe

when I write it like you suggested, the selectMenu duplicates itself,
just creates another selectmenu as many times as I run the refresh.. frustrating.
this is the HTML after the refresh:

```
<a id="ddlReportFarms-button" class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-selectmenu-dropdown" aria-owns="ddlReportFarms-menu" aria-haspopup="true" href="#" role="button" style="width: 198px;">
<span class="ui-selectmenu-status">Select Farm</span>
<span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
</a>
<a id="ddlReportFarms-button" class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-selectmenu-dropdown ui-corner-all" aria-owns="ddlReportFarms-menu" aria-haspopup="true" href="#" role="button" style="width: 198px;">
<span class="ui-selectmenu-status">Select Farm</span>
<span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: In the original question you're saying *when this happens again*... what exactly do you mean by that? Page reload? Either case, could you add more of your code, specifically the part that calls the function calling this code?

Comment: I meant when I run $('#ddlReportFarms').selectmenu() a second time;
but ignore that, I'm not doing that now.. what happens now is : 1) $('#ddlReportFarms').selectmenu()  2) after the user does something I add a few <option>s to ddlReportFarms 3) I run $('#ddlReportFarms').selectmenu('refresh', true);
in IE, the selectMenu refreshes but duplicates itself and in FF does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Which version of selectmenu do you use?

My fork has no method refresh but your proposal is correct (aka uing selectmenu() on a already initialized selectmenu to refresh it). Please see the wiki for more information: https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu