# Select Not showing the rest of options list when using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got code that shows a hidden select menu and then appends options to it. I refresh the select menu but for some reason only the first element in the select menu appears and when you click on the select the rest of the list doesn't appear. Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#searchpage',
function()
{
    $('#searchuniversity').change(
    function() 
    {
        var IDSelected = $("#searchuniversity").val();
        alert(IDSelected);
        $('#searchuniversitycampus').empty();
        var Arrayiterate = ArrayCampus[IDSelected];
        var SelectDropDown = document.getElementById("searchuniversitycampus");

        for (var i = 0; i < Arrayiterate.length; i++) 
        {
            var arrayofcampus = Arrayiterate[i];
            alert(arrayofcampus[0]);
            var NewOption = new Option(arrayofcampus[0],arrayofcampus[1]);
            SelectDropDown.add(NewOption);
        };
        $("#searchuniversitycampus").closest('div.ui-select').show();
        $('#searchuniversitycampus').selectmenu('refresh',true);
    });

}
);
```

basically the loop works but not drop down list appears when I click the select menu.

Answer (score 0):

The winning answer is:

```
$('#searchuniversitycampus').selectmenu({'refresh': true});
```

The refresh has to be done like this to have the list show! Got the answer from the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471780/jquery-selectmenu-refresh-doesnt-work)

Comment: `$('#searchuniversitycampus').selectmenu('refresh');` easier :)